# Mi codigo de js me tira un error de console con el addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css3

```js
const slider = document.querySelector("#slider"); 
let sliderSection = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section"); 
let sliderSectionLast = sliderSection[sliderSection.length -1];
const btnLeft = document.querySelector("#btn-left"); 
const btnRight = document.querySelector("#btn-right");

slider.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', sliderSectionLast);

function Next(){ 

let sliderSectionFirst = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section")[0]; 
slider.style.marginLeft = "-200%"; 
slider.style.transition = "all 0.5s"; 

setTimeout(function(){ 
    
    slider.style.transition = "none"; 
    slider.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', sliderSectionFirst); 
    slider.style.marginLeft = "-100%"; 
}, 500); 
}

function Prev(){ 

let sliderSection = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section"); 
let sliderSectionLast = sliderSection[sliderSection.length -1]; 
slider.style.marginLeft = "0"; 
slider.style.transition = "all 0.5s"; 

setTimeout(function(){ 
    
    slider.style.transition = "none"; 
    slider.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', sliderSectionLast) 
    slider.style.marginLeft = "-100%"; 

}, 500); 

} 

btnRight.addEventListener('click', function(){ 

Next(); 

}); 

btnLeft.addEventListener('click', function(){ 

Prev(); 

});
```

Comment: agrega tu codigo HTML que si no tenemos que imaginarnoslo

Comment: Porque usas query selector, para obtener un elemento por su `id` de esta forma : `const btnLeft = document.querySelector("#btn-left");`, en vez de usar directamente  `document.getElementById("btn-left")`, lee https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Pon en el título _cuál es el problema en cuestión_. Haz que no parezca _clickbait_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Si no van a responder lo que puse, no vengan a comentar, el error ya lo habia solucionado, no digan estupideces, en especial el primer comentario y el tercero. Gracias, y traten de buena manera a la gente